# Alternative to appletviewer in jdk12

Tags: java, applet, awt, java-12

Is there any alternative to applet viewer in JDK12?

I am new to Java and I tried to add AWT checkbox in Java
It runs fine in JDK 1.8, but not running in JDK12.

I searched over internet and found that the applet viewer is Deprecated. 
(The Applet API is deprecated, no replacement) on the official oracle's help web page.

I search about this problem and got no satisfying answers so I posted here...

```
import java.applet
import java.awt.*;

 /*
<applet code="CreateCheckBox" width=200 height=200>
</applet>
*/
public class CreateCheckBox extends Applet{

public void init(){
    Checkbox checkBox1 = new Checkbox();
    checkBox1.setLabel("My Checkbox 1");
    Checkbox checkbox2 = new Checkbox("My Checkbox 2");
    add(checkBox1);
    add(checkbox2);
}
}
```

It should work in JDK12 because it runs in JDK1.8.

Comment: No. Rewrite for another launching technology.

Comment: What makes you think that something should work with JDK 12 just because it worked in JDK 1.8. This is just wishfull thinking. Actually the main problem with Applets is not JDK 12. The main problem is that modern browsers just don't support applets anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is officially no way to run applets on Java 11 or later:

- The `appletviewer` application has been removed.
- The `java.applet.*` classes that applets depend on have been removed.

  **Correction** : They haven't done this yet, but I expect they will soon.

Applets should be treated as dead technology.

You could *conceivably* implement your own version of the `appletviewer` classes and put them together with your applet code into a JAR file.  It should work.  However, it is a bad idea.  The primary use-case for applets was to embed Java in websites, and that won't work because modern browsers no longer support Java plugins.  (Indeed, many recent browsers actively block Java plugins!)

The best thing to do is to rewrite applets using different technology, depending on what they do:

- AWT / Swing
- JavaFX
- SWT
- HTML 5
- etcetera

---

You said:

> It should work in JDK12 because it runs in JDK1.8.

This is not logically correct.

Comment: @Stephen_C I am not getting ClassDefNotFoundError. The class file is generating and there is no problem in compilation. I appreciate your answer but as I said I am learning so to complete some of my assignments I need to use applet. Thank you

Comment: 1. Do your course assignments using Java 8.   2. At the end of your course when they ask for anonymous feedback, point out that the course is teaching deprecated technology.  Get your friends to do the same.  Suggest they teach JavaFX or Android instead.